# integrating sorcery in a checkoutprocess

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'd like to integrate the sorcery-gem to achieve authentication while checking out in an online shop. I followed Ryan Bate's Railscast [episode 283 - authentication with Sorcery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery).

Given a vistor has put together some products in his `session[:cart]` and now wants to checkout. He clicks on "checkout" and the RailsApp checks if he is already logged in. If not, he will be redirected to sessions#new and got to log in.

The problem is that [sorcery's #login](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sorcery/0.7.0/Sorcery/Controller/InstanceMethods#login-instance_method) does a `session_reset` and so also `session[:cart]` will be destroyed.

Is there a nifty solution for that? I just can think of some, imho, dirty hacks like creating new controller actions or trying to save the cart temporarily in the database.

Cheers, CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do something like this in your session controller (the place you call login):

```
temp_cart = session[:cart]
login(…)
session[:cart] = temp_cart
```

This way you'll hand your cart around the session reset.

Bests,
JJS